# How to sum matrix which had been already rearranged

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

I have some matrix :

```
A = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6;
      1 2 3 4 5 6]

B = [ 6 5 4 3 2 1;
      6 5 4 3 2 1]

C = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6;
      1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

what is code to make this following matrix:

```
Result = [1 2 9 9 10 11 5 5 5 6;
          1 2 9 9 10 11 5 5 5 6]
```

Note : Actually the above matrix is sum of 3 matrix above which had been already rearranged like as the following matrix. #sum is sum which is based on column.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 2 3 4 5 6
    6 5 4 3 2 1
    6 5 4 3 2 1
        1 2 3 4 5 6
        1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And. I sum first row by first row, and second row by second row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do what you say above:

```
Result = zeros(size(A) + [0,4]);
Result(:,1:size(A,2)) = A;
Result(:,3:end-2) = Result(:,3:end-2) + B;
Result(:,5:end) = Result(:, 5:end) + C;
```

The point is, you can select a subregion of a matrix, and assign another matrix to it. You just have to make sure both sides of the assignment are the same shape.